# Matrix computation without for loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get faster computation for a piece of code and want to get rid of the for loop. I have three vectors roll, pitch and heading. I have to get the rotation matrix for each value of roll,pitch and heading. Right now, my code is

```
for i=1:size(roll,1)
    R1_r = [1 0 0; 0 cos(roll(i)) -sin(roll(i)); 0 sin(roll(i)) cos(roll(i))];
    R2_p = [cos(pitch(i)) 0 sin(pitch(i)); 0 1 0; -sin(pitch(i)) 0 cos(pitch(i))];
    R3_h = [cos(head(i)) sin(head(i)) 0; -sin(head(i)) cos(head(i)) 0; 0 0 1];
    R = R3_h*R2_p*R1_r;
    x1(i,2:4) = (R*x(i,2:4)')';
end
```

I want to replace the entire for loop. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The main way that I can see would be to expand the last line on a piece of paper, and write a vectorized equivalent. How big is `size(roll,1)` exactly? Have you run the profiler to confirm that this is your bottleneck?

Comment: size(roll,1) is around 500,000 records in one case. Yes, this is the bottleneck.

Comment: Well then there is no secret, take a piece of paper and expand the matrix product... :) Once you have the expansion, vectorizing is trivial (you can edit your post if you still don't know how).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was a simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will expand the last product for you:

```
syms roll pitch yaw x1 x2 x3

R1 = [1 0 0; 0 cos(roll) -sin(roll); 0 sin(roll) cos(roll)];
R2 = [cos(pitch) 0 sin(pitch); 0 1 0; -sin(pitch) 0 cos(pitch)];
R3 = [cos(yaw) sin(yaw) 0; -sin(yaw) cos(yaw) 0; 0 0 1];
R  = R3*R2*R1;
x  = [x1;x2;x3];

R*x
```

output:

```
 x2*(cos(roll)*sin(yaw) + cos(yaw)*sin(pitch)*sin(roll)) - x3*(sin(roll)*sin(yaw) - cos(roll)*cos(yaw)*sin(pitch)) + x1*cos(pitch)*cos(yaw)
 x2*(cos(roll)*cos(yaw) - sin(pitch)*sin(roll)*sin(yaw)) - x3*(cos(yaw)*sin(roll) + cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw)) - x1*cos(pitch)*sin(yaw)
                                                                          x3*cos(pitch)*cos(roll) - x1*sin(pitch) + x2*cos(pitch)*sin(roll)
```

Based on this, you should take the sines and cosines of your angles:

```
cp = cos(pitch); sp = sin(pitch);
cr = cos(roll);  sr = sin(roll);
cy = cos(yaw);   sy = sin(yaw);
```

and replace `x1 -> x1(:,2)`, `x2 -> x1(:,3)` and `x3 -> x1(:,4)` in the above formula, changing the `*` signs with `.*` where needed.

The final code should look like this:

```
x1_new = x1(:,3).*(cr.*sy + cy.*sp.*sr) - x1(:,4).*(sr.*sy - cr.*cy.*sp) + x1(:,2).*cp.*cy;
x2_new = x1(:,3).*(cr.*cy - sp.*sr.*sy) - x1(:,4).*(cy.*sr + cr.*sp.*sy) - x1(:,2).*cp.*sy;
x3_new = x1(:,4).*cp.*cr - x1(:,2).*sp + x1(:,3).*cp.*sr;
```

Be **careful** not to replace the columns of x1 as you go; you need to store the results in new columns, otherwise you will corrupt the rest of the calculation. After these three lines you can replace safely the columns of x1.